# The strength of negative regression coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic

Does a logistic regression coefficient of -.222 demonstrate a stronger effect than a logistic regression coefficient of -.087? The negatives confuse me as to whether a coefficient closer to 1 indicates a stronger effect. Thank you!

Comment: Just as in plain regression, a coefficient in logistic regression depends on the units of he predictor as well as the magnitude of any effect. So, what is more telling is each coefficient divided by its standard error, which ratio is necessarily unit-free. Whatever software you are using should provide results on that.  Conversely if predictors happen to have the same units of measurement, then to that extent they are comparable.

Comment: Further from zero is the metric, with nothing else said. There is no special meaning to coefficients being (near to) 1; as said in many cases the units of the predictor affect coefficient magnitudes.

Comment: Could you edit the title to make it more informative?

Comment: There's nothing special about negative logistic regression coefficients.  This follows from the fact that you made an arbitrary choice when doing the calculations: you assigned the value $1$ to one of the outcome categories and $0$ to the other.  If you had reversed that assignment the calculations would be equally applicable--but all regression coefficients would be negated as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The logistic regression coefficient is a log-odds ratio. The results from a logistic regression model are usually reported by exponentiating the coefficients and their 95% CIs. The null hypothesis (no effect) is when the odds ratio is 1, e.g. the odds of outcome does not differ comparing groups among exposure levels. The odds ratio is bounded by 0 and infinity.

An odds ratio of 0 is a perfect negative relationship (the likelihood of outcome is a negative step function with 1 probability *below* a certain threshold and 0 probability *above* a certain threshold.

A log odds ratio of -0.222 is an odds ratio of 0.8. A log odds ratio of -0.087 translates to an odds ratio of 0.92. The first value, 0.8 indicates a stronger negative relationship between exposure and outcome.